# Can't find IIS AppPool Identity

Tags: iis

I have a Win 2008 R2 Enterprise machine that is running fine several websites each one with its own app pool.

I have no troubles giving permissions (using windows GUI) to IIS AppPool\A, IIS AppPool\B, etc... But today I have created one more app pool "C" and I can't find it in the GUI nor using icacls command. I'm trying to give permissions in a folder to IIS AppPool\C but it says it can't find! I'm including built-in security principals in the search and if I type any of the existing app pool identities windows finds then Ok. The problem is just with this new one.

Does anyone knows what is going on?

I don't know if it is reladed but the only change made to this server was to enable .net 3.5 WCF Activation for http and non-http. After enabling this, I got error in all my .net 4 sites and fixed by running aspnet_regiis.exe /iru as described here http://devonenote.com/2010/06/could-not-load-type-system-servicemodel-activation-httpmodule .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out you need to start the associated IIS application for the first time before you can see your application pool in the windows GUI!